# How to move items of a column down in a pandas dataframe, but only after the nth item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a program that goes through the output of an ocr scan of a table and writes it to a dataframe. Sometimes the rows merge, resulting in squished cells that also contain content that was supposed to be in the cell below, shortening the column. For these cells, I want to be able to turn A --> B.

edit: I forgot to mention that I already have a function that can detect merged cells, I just need to know how to split them and modify the dataframe accordingly.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | a |
| b c | b |
| d | c |
| - | d |

I could not find a solution that involved shifting only a certain part of the column down as opposed to shifting the entire column down. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 functions. One identifying the merged cells and another that splits the merged cells.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already have the function to detect merged cells. That's my bad.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. Try using the str.split() function from pandas.